# Function not being called synchronously?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-sql

I'm having a problem with some code not performing as expected, I should probably explain what it's doing first:

- On document load function selectForLists is querying a sqlite DB
  containing football scores, specifically a table called matches, then
  calling function renderLists.
- RenderLists puts the playing team into a sorted list with duplicates
  removed.
- Then for each entry in this list of teams function latestTest is
  being called, which selects all rows from the match table where that
  team is playing and calls latestTest2.
- LatestTest2 counts the number of rows with that team playing and
  outputs some code to the inserted div.
- Once that has been completed for every team it should revert to
  finish the renderLists function and call the loaded function, except
  it doesnt and I have to add a delay to calling this function because
  it doesnt happen last.

I'm hoping someone can tell me whats wrong here, why the loaded function isn't called after all the above is completed? Also if anyone has any tips for achieving the same outcome with more efficient code I would like that very much.

Apologies for this long post, I'm sure many will find the code terrible and I know there are too many functions and probably many better ways of doing this but its been a few years since working with javascript in uni and I'm struggling with it and sqlite.

The code is below or at http://pastebin.com/7AxXzHNB thanks

```
function selectForLists() { //called on (document).ready
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM matches', [], renderLists);
    });
}

function renderLists(tx, rs) {
    var playingList = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
        playingList.push(rs.rows.item(i)['playing']);
    }

    playingListSort = playingList.sort();
    var playingListFinal = new Array();

    playingListSort.forEach(function(value) {
        if (playingListFinal.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            playingListFinal.push(value);
        }
    });

    for (var c = 0; c < playingListFinal.length; c++) {
        latestTest(playingListFinal[c]);
    }

    loaded(); //not running last in the function
    //setTimeout(loaded,1000);
    /////Using a delay because it doesn't run after the above has completed
}

function latestTest(team) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM matches WHERE playing="' + team + '"', [], latestTest2);
    });
}

function latestTest2(tx, rs) {
    counted = rs.rows.length;
    var theFunction = rs.rows.item(0)['playing'];

    $('#inserted').append('<li onclick="onToDate(\'' + theFunction + '\')"><img width="30px"        height="25px" id="popupContactClose" src="style/soccer.png"><div id="popupContactClose2">' + counted + '</div></img>' + rs.rows.item(0)['playing'] + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: Is this code running in a browser? How are you connecting directly to a database?

Comment: yea its in a browser, another page creates the database in localstorage

Comment: @MattBall it's the deprecated Web SQL API.

Comment: @mao [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). The API your using is deprecated. I recommend you use [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) instead. It has better browser support aswell

Comment: @MattBall It's HTML5; there are databases now.

Comment: @Raynos thanks, I had no idea it was deprecated I will have a look at this

Comment: @mao as an aside, do you really need a client-side database. Don't overlook servers & `localStorage` for data persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latestTest` function calls another `executeSQL` function with its own callback. *That* callback will be executed when the SQL has finished, which will be at an arbitrary time.

The `renderLists` function will continue execution (including calling the `loaded` function) normally, quite apart from anything having to do with the callbacks in `latestTests` being executed.

Your mistake is thinking that `loaded` will "wait" to be executed--you will still have pending callbacks from the DB code in `latestTest`.

Comment: ahh I understand now, thanks for the explanation. Can you think of any way to call loaded when sql has done its business?

Comment: @mao I'd first try to do more in SQL; it's good at sorting and grouping. You could combine more logic into `latestTest` by selecting all the teams and doing the team differentiating in JavaScript, and call `loaded` from a reworked `latestTest2`. You could use the [synchronous API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#synchronous-database-api), but what Raynos is saying is probably worth paying attention to.

Comment: ok thanks, that all makes sense. I tried that earlier and  I couldnt get latestTest and latestTest2 combined into the same function. I will try some more now I know what exactly is happening.

Comment: @mao Okay. Make sure to accept an answer; questions about asynch stuff comes up a *lot* in JS, first with Ajax stuff, now with the DB API... *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

Both `db.transaction` and `tx.executeSql` are asynchronous functions, just like `setTimeout`, where if you write

```
setTimeout(function(){
    doLater();
}, 1000)
doNow();
```

`doNow()` will execute *before* `doLater()` because the callback function you created will get called at some future time.

In your case, `latestTest()` calls `db.transaction`, and then `tx.executeSql`, both of which are asynchronous. That means, the callback function `latestTest2` will get called at some future time, which will be *after* when `loaded()` gets called.

Comment: Yea,I didn't realise before that the database/sql functions were asynchronous. I wanted to avoid using the time delay on the loaded function because I don't know exactly how long the functions I want it called after will take. Is there any event I can use to call loaded after the database/sql functions are complete?